# Problems to reset password - $wgPasswordReminderResendTime

Tags: mediawiki

when i tried to reset a password a received a messages: "A password reset email has already been sent, within the last 24 hours. To prevent abuse, only one password reset email will be sent per 24 hours."

in LocalSettings.php i inserted the line below:
$wgPasswordReminderResendTime" =1;

after it i restarted the sql and apache and the message remains the same.

Should i configure in another place?

My MediaWiki is version 1.34

i appreciate your help

Regards

Gustavo

Comment: That's the right place and right config flag to set, you must be getting something else wrong.

Comment: I guess you changed the variable after a first attempt of reset?

Comment: Reset timer is stored in the database, so your new parameter will hopefully be taken in account when the previous one has expired.